# C# Get index from List where value is in a range

Tags: c#, list, linq

Let's say I have a `List<float>` with the following values:

```
{20, 60, 80, 85, 90, 120, 140}
```

And I have one number, let's suppose "75".
How can I find the index where this number I have (75) is >= then an index's value and < then the next index's value?
In basic words, I want to find that my number (75), is "inside" the range between 60 and 80, so it returns to me index number 1.

So far, I've used Linq but it only returns to me the nearest value. I'd like to find the Index instead.

```
myList.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(points - x)).First()
```

Is there an efficient way to return to me this index? I know there's the possibility to use a For loop, but I believe that a loop may be heavy if I take into consideration that I may have to call this a couple of times in a few seconds. (The list will contain ~99 values).

Thank you very much! I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a simple LINQ or something expression, the best way is to use a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood what you meant.

Following should help you

```
var list = new List<float>{20, 60, 80, 85, 90, 120, 140};
var numberToSearch = 70;
var result = list.Select((x,index)=> new 
                                     {
                                       Index=index, 
                                       Value=x, 
                                       Diff = Math.Abs(x-numberToSearch)
                                     })
                 .OrderBy(x=>x.Diff)
                 .First()
                 .Index;
Console.WriteLine($"Search Term {numberToSearch}, Index={result}");
```

Alternatively (if the list is sorted initially), you could also do

```
var result = list.Select((x,index)=> new {number=x, index= index}).First(x=> x.number > numberToSearch).index - 1;

if(result == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Search Term {numberToSearch}, Index={result}");
}
```

Output for `numberToSearch = 70`

```
Search Term 70, Index=1
```

Output for `numberToSearch = 87`

```
Search Term 87, Index=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a `for` loop will be fast. The accepted answer has an `OrderBy` (has time complexity of `nlogn`), but assuming your list is already sorted, and you can try this:

```
var myList = new List<float>{20, 60, 80, 85, 90, 120, 140};
var numberToSearch = 75;
var foundIndex = -1;

for(var i=0; i<myList.Count; i++)
{
    if(myList[i] >= numberToSearch)
    {
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(foundIndex<=0)
{
    // Element was not found
}
else
{
    // the desired range is: [foundIndex-1, foundIndex], i.e. (1,2)
}
```

Comment: Now that you said that, it reminds me that I can't sort my list. Because it would change the indexes. A for loop would give me more freedom to manipulate the items. Thank you mshsayem!

Comment: @mshayem The answer was ordering temporary anonymous objects, where Index was maintained as a property. The original index was never comprimised.

Comment: @curiousUser If your list is not sorted, this will not work, but Anu VIswan's answer will work. If your list is not sorted initially, this answer should not be accepted :). I _assumed_ that your list is initially sorted.

Comment: @AnuViswan Yes. I forgot to mention my _assumption_ that, the list is originally sorted. If it is not sorted, this solution will not work.

Comment: @mshsayem That makes sense. Also, your approach does the minimal loops.  My only question would be should this myList[i] > numberToSearch be myList[i] >= numberToSearch ? what happens if user search 60. What should the method return ?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your collection is of primitive type, you can use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) of List collection.Please try this:

```
myList.IndexOf(myList.Where(f => f.x >= points).OrderBy(f => f).First())
```

Comment: That works! Thanks Sam! I think it's faster than Linq.Select, is it?

Comment: @curiousUser I think we are comparing apples and oranges. Select functionality is different than IndexOf. And in your case, you definitely don't need select as you are just looking for index. I would say, doing select is an additional step/operation which you actually don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a method that looks at the first number (20), if it is not greater than 75, it puts 20 in a method and it moves onto the next number (40), since it is not greater than 75 it replaces the method that stores 20, with the number 40, then it moves onto the next number, that should happen until it reaches 80. Once it reaches 80, then It should read that 80 is greater than 75. Then take the method that stores the number before it, which would be 60, and it would put 75 in between them.

Comment: Can you provide an example with code so that your answer can be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @mshsayem is correct but much nicer code will be

```
        var list = new List<float>{20, 60, 80, 85, 90, 120, 140};
        var numberToSearch = 70;
        var foundIndex = myList.FindIndex(_ => _ > numberToSearch);
        if (foundIndex < 0) // not found;
        if(foundIndex == 0) // found but first element
        else // index foundIndex-1 and foundIndex
```

It will not check further elements when getting hit.

Comment: My answer is not correct if the list is not initially sorted.

Comment: @mshsayem If it is initially not sorted, my answer is also incorrect.